# Read from XML Using Linq and add it to a list containing objects

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list

I'm trying to read from an XML file and add every contact to the contacts list the error i get is that can't convert List to List

writes an xml file for each contact in contacts (Works)

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    var xEle = new XElement("Contact",
        from contact in contacts
        select new XElement("Contact",
            new XAttribute("Name", contact.Name),
                new XElement("Address", contact.StreetAddress),
                new XElement("AreaCode", contact.AreaCode),
                new XElement("City", contact.City),
                new XElement("Phone", contact.Phone),
                new XElement("Email", contact.Email)
                ));
        xEle.Save(path + "\\contacts.xml");
```

Reads from the xml and adds it to the list (DOES NOT WORK!)

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\contacts.xml");
contacts = (List<Contact>)xmlDoc.Descendants("Contact");
```

XML File Output

```
<Contacts>
    <Contact Name="Nils Nilsson">
        <Address>MyStreet 17B</Address>
        <AreaCode>55555</AreaCode>
        <City>BigCity</City>
        <Phone>0705555555</Phone>
        <Email>mail@gmail.com</Email>
    </Contact>
</Contact>
```

Contact Class

```
 public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        public string AreaCode { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

My existing list

```
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
```

Comment: `xmlDoc.Descendants("Contact")` returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`. You need to deserialize those `XElement`s to your `Contact`object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, the reason your original code doesn't work is that all queries in LINQ to XML return some form of `XObject` - most commonly an `XAttribute` or `XElement`.  It won't map anything to `Contact`.

The easiest way to map your XML to your objects is to make use of built in support for XML Serialization.  You class needs a couple of attributes & an extra class to map to your XML structure:

```
[XmlRoot("Contacts")]
public class Contacts : List<Contact>
{

}

public class Contact
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Address")]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    public string AreaCode { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And then read your XML as follows:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(Path.Combine(path, "contacts.xml"))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Contacts));
    var contacts = (Contacts)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Note you can also use the `Serialize` method to create the XML in the first instance.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. I overlooked the properties and didn't realized the differences in PropertyName and that Name is an Attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\contacts.xml");
var xElements = xmlDoc.Descendants("Contact");
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Contact));
contacts = xElements.Select(xe => (Contact)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xe.CreateReader())).ToList();
```

Comment: Works great! but it seems to add the contacts on index 1 instead of 0 for some reason